# Why can't I CTRL drag an action for storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I am new to iOS programming and using iOS 6. I see that, using XCode I can CTRL+drag action and outlets for button sand text field but not for the storyboard. I want to do some action when user clicks on the storyboard (taps away from the text field).

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)editingEnded:(UITextField *)sender {
    NSLog(@"%@", @"in editingEnded");
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender {
    if(_firstClick) {
        [_textField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I guess, you asked me to implement something like `editingEnded`? This is my delegate for `editing did end` action (how can I confirm this, there is no such annotation/attribute attached to this method?). However, this method alone didn't work. When i added the 2nd method `buttonSelected` as a delegate for another button on the story board, then `editingEnded` is also called due to `[_textField resignFirstResponder];`.

Answer (score 1):

A storyboard is a container which contains your various UI elements, including your text field.

What you *really* want to do is set a delegate for your text field, which you can do with your view controller.

Then, when you click away from the text field, you can catch that happening via the delegate method ["`textFieldDidEndEditing:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldDidEndEditing%3a).  You implement that function in your view controller, make certain your text field has your view controller set as the delegate, and you should be able to do whatever you want within your view controller's implementation of the "`textFieldDidEndEditing:`" function.

Comment: I added some code to my question, do you have idea about this issue?